# error: package org.jclouds.logging.slf4j.config does not exist ( the class SLF4JLoggingModule )

Tags: maven, slf4j, jclouds

The import specified at the example http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/quickstart/openstack/ fails:

```
import org.jclouds.logging.slf4j.config.SLF4JLoggingModule;
...
Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SLF4JLoggingModule());
```

The dependencies were added following the instruccions at http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/userguide/installation-guide/:
pom.xml:

```
...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jclouds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-allcompute</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jclouds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-allblobstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

**1) Add the dependency** of the artifact jclouds-slf4j (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jclouds.driver/jclouds-slf4j/1.5.4)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jclouds.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**2) Rebuild the project**

The pom.xml may look like this:

```
...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jclouds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-allcompute</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jclouds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-allblobstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jclouds.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Comment: A short update: This happened to me with the current version of the getting started guide http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/ as well. For the current version 1.9.2 the groupId is `<groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>`

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I wrote that doc.

The [Get jclouds](http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/quickstart/openstack/#install) section on that page previously read

> Follow the instructions for [Getting the binaries using Apache Ant](http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/userguide/installation-guide/).

But only linked to the Installation guide at the top. It should have linked directly to the [Getting the binaries using Apache Ant](http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/userguide/installation-guide/#ant) section which has the jclouds-slf4j driver in it.

I've added anchors to the Installation guide so you can link into individual sections now. Hope that helps clear it up.